# numerical integration of multivariate normal distribution in R

Tags: r, numerical-integration

I'm trying to find a solution of `t1 and t2` with the condition below

```
# x1 and x2 are bivariate normal distributed with 
mu1=mu2=0
cov=matrix(c(1,1/2,1/2,1),2,2)

# trying to find the solution satisfying the equality with  t1=t2
# p(x1>t1) + p(x1<t2,x2>t2) = 0.05
```

I'm wondering if anyone could help me with code in R.THX!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R, your probability of interest is

```
  pnorm(t, lower.tail = FALSE) + 
    pmvnorm(c(-Inf,t), c(t,Inf), sigma = Sigma) 



library(mvtnorm)
Sigma <- rbind(c(1,0.5),c(0.5,1))
f <- function(t){
  pnorm(t, lower.tail = FALSE) + 
    pmvnorm(c(-Inf,t), c(t,Inf), sigma = Sigma) - 0.05
}

uniroot(f, c(-6,6))
# $root
# [1] 1.916334
```

Answer (score 1):

`p(x1>t) + p(x1<t,x2>t) = 0.05` is the same as `p(x1<t,x2<t) = 0.95`. Thus:

```
library(mvtnorm)
qmvnorm(0.95, mean = rep(0, 2), sigma = cov)
#$quantile
#[1] 1.916399
#
#$f.quantile
#[1] 2.600961e-06
#
#attr(,"message")
#[1] "Normal Completion"
```

Check:

```
pmvnorm(c(1.916399, -Inf), c(Inf, Inf), , mean = rep(0, 2), sigma = cov) +
  pmvnorm(c(-Inf, 1.916399), c(1.916399, Inf), , mean = rep(0, 2), sigma = cov)
#[1] 0.04999262
#attr(,"error")
#[1] 2e-16
#attr(,"msg")
#[1] "Normal Completion"
```

Comment: One of use is doing an error. I find the opposite.

Comment: I'm clearly wrong. `P(x1 > -1.916334)` is `> 1/2`.

Comment: Ah no sorry, I find the same.